# media player play song with buffer

Tags: android, media-player

I'm trying to play live stream mp3 audio by media player.
The problem is that when I am using URL, it blocks UI thread for sometime then it works fine. But I need that it plays the song with the buffering as well.

Thanks in Advance.Please help.

```
    try {
             audioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            audioPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            audioPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            audioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(useFrontSpeaker ? AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL : AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            audioPlayer.reset();
            audioPlayer.setDataSource(mSongDetail.getPath());
            audioPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        audioDuration = audioPlayer.getDuration();
        audioPlayer.start();

        startProgressTimer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (audioPlayer != null) {
            audioPlayer.reset();
            audioPlayer.release();
            audioPlayer = null;
            isPaused = false;
            MusicPreferance.playingSongDetail = null;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Post program related questions here..not general questions...Post your code...something you have tried??

Comment: I have added code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use audioPlayer.prepareAsync() + asyncHandler for it, or use a separate Thread.